# How can we access and add applications under Full Disk access pane programmatically

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, macos-catalina, full-disk-access

With new security and permission related checks included in Mojave and Catalina. In my swift application I am trying to create a copy of file using below function
“open func copyItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) throws”
As I call this function , my application entry is created under Full Disk Access panel of  Security & Privacy in System Preferences. Unless until I enable this I can’t create a copy of my file using the function I mentioned above.

My issue: This entry getting added to the Full Disk Access is happening silently, I don't see any security alert asking me to allow or don't allow. We don't even have any API to get this information , so that we can  ask user to manually add it.

Where can I get appropriate documentation about Full Disk access feature which will help to understand which locations are restricted to access and how can I enable it programmatically without users interference